# How to get the nsuserdefault value in other viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have two viewcontrollers. In my first viewcontroller:

```
{           
    NSString *string=textField.text;  
    NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  

    [data setObject:string forKey:@"strings"];
    [data synchronize];
}
```

How do I get the string value in my other viewcontroller?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Here you can use this in anyway in your application for store value of NSUserDefaults.**

```
// --- Saving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];  
// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];
// saving a Double
[prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];
// saving a Float
[prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];
// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
[prefs synchronize];
```

**Here you can use this in anyway in your application for get value of NSUserDefaults.**

```
// --- Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults =  [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *myString = [defaults stringForKey:@"strings"];
```

THis is the way to retrieve the data. Please note `NSUserDefault` is not used to pass data between two controllers. There are better methods for that.

**Edit : After seeing Shaan Singh's comment**

To pass data 2 view controllers you can declare a property in second view controller and access that from the present view controller.

It is already answered brilliantly [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: I agree with Kir. What other good methods are there to passing data between controllers?

Answer (score 4):

you can access `NSUserDefaults` in any controller (Any class of your application) of your application with the same code you have written in one class.

for getting the string value use the below code

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString *myString = [data objectForKey:@"strings"];
```

Answer (score 3):

In the other ViewController,

```
NSUserDefaults *data = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
NSString *string = [data objectForKey:@"strings"];
```

This will work because `NSUserDefaults` are a global key-value store that will persist across classes and applications.